# Should I normalize this database design further?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio, ef-code-first

I have the following database design:

```
TABLE [Document]
[DocumentId] [int] NOT NULL, --Primary Key
[Status] [bit] NULL,
[Text] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[FolderPath] [nvarchar](max) NULL

TABLE [Metadata]
[MetadataId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, -- Primary Key
[DocumentId] [int] NOT NULL,               -- Foreign Key Document.DocumentId (1:1 relationship)
[Title] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
[Author] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL

TABLE [Page](
[PageId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,     -- Primary Key
[DocumentId] [int] NOT NULL,               -- Foreign Key Document.DocumentId (1:N Relationship)
[Number] [int] NOT NULL,
[ImagePath] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[PageText] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL

TABLE [Word](
[WordId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,     -- Primary Key
[PageId] [int] NOT NULL,                   -- Foreign Key Page.PageId (1:N Relationship)
[Text] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL

TABLE [Keyword](
[KeywordId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  -- Primary Key
[Word] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL

TABLE [DocumentKeyword](
[Document_DocumentId] [int] NOT NULL,     -- Foreign Key Document.DocumentId  (N:N Relationship)
[Keyword_KeywordId] [int] NOT NULL        -- Foreign Key Keyword.KeywordId
```

I'm using Entity Framework Code First to create the database.

Should I be normalizing my database design further? i.e. creating link tables between Document and Page, Document and Metadata, etc.? If so, is there a way to get the Entity Framework to do create the relationship tables for me, so that I don't have to include them in my models? I'm trying to learn to do this the right and most efficient way possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can't immediately answer your question, but I have some thoughts that might improve your design:

1. A document (in real life, at least) can be written by more than one
   author. This means, that your 1:1 relationship from Document to
   Metadata should be a 1:n relationship (unless you can prove that
   there will never be a situation that there's more than one author)
2. The title of a document is (in my view) more a property of the document than a piece of metadata (also having 1. in mind)
3. What does this Word table do?
4. The column Keyword_KeywordId should be called plainly KeywordId if you want to be consistent in your naming. The same applies to
   Document_DocumentId.

For the rest it looks pretty normalized

Comment: 1. Should I create an Author Table? I also have other fields like Collector, Owner etc. not shown above. Would I need to create tables for each, or could I use a catch all "Person" table? 
3. This database is for OCR'ing images of documents. The word table contains the images and position of words in a document. In the interest of brevity, I omitted columns.
4. The column names were created automatically by entity framework. Is there a way to specify a specific name?

Comment: I can't take decisions for you, since I don't know the specification. If you allow more than one author per document, I guess it'll be best to create an author table. If you don't store much more information than just a name and a last name, and the same is true for all other persons in your database, you can decide to pool the tables. But I'd personally would start with modelling each kind of person as a separate entity. Merging those is easy, but splitting isn't. I don't mind which naming convention you use, but I can only recommend to let it be consistent.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the "people" and put them in new tables. I had to make a couple more changes, but your feedback helped.